were thus to be taken "with a grain of salt", and therefore less seriously

Hypotheses of the phrase's origin include Pliny the Elder's Naturalis Historia, regarding the discovery of a recipe for an antidote to a poison.[2] In the antidote, one of the ingredients was a grain of salt. Threats involving the poison were thus to be taken "with a grain of salt", and therefore less seriously.

Source

What is the literal meaning of the bold part?
What is the relationship between one of the ingredients being a grain of salt and the threats being taken with a grain of salt?


I don't understand Does the 'taken "with a grain of salt"' part have the literal meaning?

"were to be taken" expresses an expected or required behaviour. See e.g. this question

Literally, the bold part says, that if someone threatens you with the poison you should "take (=eat) a grain of salt" at the same time as you take (=receive) the threat.
This means that you take the antidote to to the poison when the person threatens you, and so you can take the threat less seriously.
The phrase uses the "are to be v3" (in the past tense) which is a passive construction used for giving instructions.

-- Oh no. I have received a letter from my enemy. He says he will put poison in my beer.
-- You should take (ie receive) that letter with a pinch of salt. If you take (ie eat) salt it will make you immune to the poison, and you won't have to worry so much.

Then the advice to "take with a pinch of salt" got an extended meaning of "don't take the threat seriously" and lost its literal meaning.

Does "taken" mean "received" or does it mean "eaten"? It is ambiguous to me. Given the "the threats involving the poison" part, it should mean "received", but given the "with a grain of salt" part, it should mean "eaten".

@Englishgood you can't eat a threat, so "received" (or "understood") is the surface meaning used - although the dual meaning of "take" is part of why the idiom works.

I almost understand it. Is the surface meaning of "threats involving the poison were thus to be taken with a grain of salt" "a grain of salt and the threats were supposed to be received together"?

You are overthinking this. It's not particularly well written.
